# Firebug and unclear div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, firebug

I view a website's source code using Firebug and I find that there are div blocks that are not clear (its font color is lighter than others). I guess these are generated by some sources, right. How can I trace these out ?
For example if I have a div like this

```
<div id="someid"><a href="" style="something">the stylish</a></div>
```

and this div is faded, I would like to use jquery to change its style for example, Will that actually work for me ?

because after I do this

```
$('#someid a').attr('style','somethingelse');
```

I can't find that faded div block anymore in my source. What happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**css**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#someid a').css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write specify css for  tags, because browsers automatically apply colors for that

```
#someid a{
  color:red;
}
```

also can change color by jQuery

```
 $('#someid a').css('color','red');
```